# How to achieve such equation?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

[image]

Hello,

I'm really fresh with LaTeX, and trying to achieve equation showed on the image. Currently I have this:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{N} \ni (x, n) \xrightarrow{\mbox{\tiny{def}}} 
    \begin{cases}
        \# \left(\sigma \left( \left[
         \begin{array}{cc}
             x & 0\\
             0 & n
          \end{array}
      \right]
      \right)\right), & \textrm{gdy} \int_{n}^{x}ydy \geqslant 2 \\
      \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} x^{i}, & \textrm{w p.p.} \\
    \end{cases}
    \\ax^{2} + bx + c = 3
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

But as a result it lacks numbers on the right (my research found those are labels...?). I'm not quite sure where too look for aligment of (2) part of equation, as my Google searches yield nothing for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
f : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{N} \ni (x, n) \xrightarrow{\mbox{\tiny{def}}} 
   & \begin{cases}
        \# \left(\sigma \left( \left[
         \begin{array}{cc}
             x & 0\\
             0 & n
          \end{array}
      \right]
      \right)\right), & \textrm{gdy} \int_{n}^{x}ydy \geqslant 2 \\
      \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} x^{i}, & \textrm{w p.p.} \\
    \end{cases}\\
    &ax^{2} + bx + c = 3
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: the spacing in the original question looks like `bmatrix` was used rather than `array`.  (input is a bit more compact.)